# When is a http 404 useful and when should i consider 503 instead?

Tags: web-services, http, service

I have a system with multiple backend databases. Sometimes i cannot reach one of them for a specific operation and i want to tell the client to retry this operation.

Should i give a 404 (i.e. i was unable to confirm that the user's request was not found because a database is unreachable) ?

Or should i return a 503 since i'm just unsure that something does not exist as i cannot verify the user's request on the database that is down?

My preference is a 503 as explained per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503

Answer (score 1):

First of: While the MDN is excellent for research, I would stick to the relevant RFCs for discussion. In this case, that would be [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231).

You are indeed correct with your preference: [503](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) is meant to indicate a temporary outage in the service, possibly resolved at a later time. That can very well be caused by an upstream service failing. Such as a database.

Throwing a 404 here would have a touch of "I cannot prove wether [Schrödinger's Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) is dead or alive. So I assert it is dead."

Comment: i know i was missing something, and it was indeed looking into the RFC. thanks!